# How to globally inject value across modules in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, nrwl

I'm working with nx workspace and nestjs.
I would like to inject a value across multiple modules in nestjs app.

Final goal is to reproduce similar way of configuration management as [vsavkin mentioned for Angular](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/208#issuecomment-384102058)

But it seems it's not possible, or I missed something.

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the FeatureService (?). Please make
>   sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the FeatureModule
>   context.

How can I notify `FeatureModule` it needs to access to this global injected value ?

This is working fine inside `AppService` (service in root module), but not in any sub modules.

Here is my code below.
Or an full example on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/98x08oz23y)

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    FeatureModule
  ],
  controllers: [
    AppController
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: 'MY-TOKEN',
      useValue: 'my-injected-value',
    }
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**feature.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    FeatureService
  ],
})
export class FeatureModule {
}
```

**feature.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('MY-TOKEN') private injectedValue: string
  ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Quote from NestJS [official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#global-modules):

> In Angular, the providers are registered in the global scope. Once defined, they're available everywhere. On the other hand, Nest encapsulates providers inside the module scope. You aren't able to use the module providers elsewhere without importing them. But sometimes, you may just want to provide a set of things which should be available always - out-of-the-box, for example: helpers, database connection, whatever. That's why you're able to make the module a **global one**.

So what you can do is just defining one global module with that `MY-TOKEN` provider:

```
@Global()
@Module({  
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'MY-TOKEN',
      useValue: 'my-injected-value',
    }
  ],
  exports: ['MY-TOKEN'],
})
export class GlobalModule {}
```

and then you can use its exported values without importing the global module anywhere.

Comment: Works like a charm. Why I didn't think about it ! Thank you very much Karol. ;-)

Comment: how about directly set the application module a global one, instead create a new module, is that ok?

Comment: @KentWood doesn't work for some reason. It's needed to import global module into app.module, if you put global decorator on the app.module, nothing changes